# how to use tornado and django on open swift

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, tornado

Recently I have been working on openswift Django(1.8) with Python(3.3). I was woundering is it possible to work with Websocket along tornado and django beacuse using of tornado will be handling the request in Asynchronous IO handler. Any good suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is an websocket implementation based on django. I would recommend taking a look. Those guys really thought on how to change django's request response paradigm in a way that it can deal with persistent connections.

There is nice [overview](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/inshort.html). They also wrote down [the concepts in detail](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/concepts.html).

Read [that one](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faqs.html?highlight=tornado#why-are-you-doing-this-rather-than-just-using-tornado-gevent-asyncio-etc) regarding the comparison with tornado.